# What is the Darkness spell used for?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I recently found a scroll to teach my mage the Darkness spell. Great. I spend half the game carting around torches to light up my surroundings, and I've found a way to do just the opposite!

What is the point of this spell? Does it make it harder for enemies to see me or anything? I've not noticed any effect, though I haven't really spent much time or energy during combat to find out.

Comment: @sean Thanks for the edit - I was feeling a little confused at the time and I get that came through in my wording!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few points where one needs to stay out of light, it helps with seeing where the light ends.

Also you should have got spell of light before that (though torches can still be useful for some puzzles).